# Codeigniter Ajax Login Form Validation

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

> I have been away from coding for a while now and coming back seems to be a lot of trouble as i tried to create an Ajax login Form using Codeigniter. Actually, everything works fine(*i mean the validation part*) but when i when i am done validating the form and should be logged in, the form just stays there, staring at me. I have tried to get rid of it and get myself logged in but i can't

**Controller:**

```
public function login()
{
    $data = array(
        'success' => false,
         'messages' => array(),
          'session_error' => false,
           'session_error_message' => array());


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]', array(
        'required' => '%s feild cannot be empty',
        'min_length' => '%s field must be at least 5 characters in length.'));



$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]', array(
        'required' => '%s feild cannot be empty',
        'min_length' => '%s field must be at least 5 characters in length.')); $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">', '</p>');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE ) {


        $user = $this->input->post('username');
        $pass = $this->input->post('password');


        if ($this->main_model->admin_login($user, $pass)) {

            $session_data = array('username' => $user);
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
            redirect(base_url() . 'admin/dashboard', 'refresh');

        } else {


            $data['session_error'] = true;
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<p class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">Invalid Username or Password</p>');
            $data['session_error_message'] = $this->session->flashdata('msg');


        }

        $data['success'] = true;
    } else {


        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }


    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**View**

```
  <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/login" method="POST" class="w3-container" id="aForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border w3-border-blue" name="username" value="Username" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" id="username">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="w3-input w3-border w3-border-blue" name="password" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" id="password">
    </div> 

    <button type="submit" name="" value="" class="w3-btn w3-border w3-border-blue">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#aForm').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.success == true) {

                if (response.session_error == true) {
                $('.text-danger').remove();
                var el = $('#password');
                el.closest('div.form-group').addClass('strong').find('.text-danger').remove();
                el.after(response.session_error_message);

            } else {

                $('.text-danger').remove();
                window.location.href = $(this).attr('action');

            }       
        }else {

            $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                var element = $('#' + key);
                element.closest('div.form-group').addClass('strong').find('.text-danger').remove();
                element.after(value);
            });

        }



    }
})
});
```

Comment: Didn't know CI was still alive. Why not use [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies in this line:

```
redirect(base_url() . 'admin/dashboard', 'refresh');
```

it works okay if not AJAX based. why it does "not work" with AJAX, is that it actually works, but instead of your current page that is redirected, it is the AJAX call that is redirected.

then, before you redirect the request, you need to check if the request was an AJAX call or not. if its not an AJAX call, then you can redirect it as usual, but if its an AJAX call, you need to reply something to the client side that the authentication is a success or a failure. for example:

```
echo json_encode(['success' => true]); // or false
```

or if the request is always AJAX call, you can skip the AJAX request check and directly **remove the redirect**, and change it to the code above

Comment: i think i already did that, the problem might be coming from my JQuery code

Comment: the code you have posted does not show you have done this, please update the code

Comment: see my emphasize, also you don't want to redirect the user to the login page in `window.location.href = $(this).attr('action');` change it to `window.location.href = 'dashboard';` or something else

Comment: you are a genius

Comment: this solves it all `$data = array(
            'success' => false,
             'messages' => array(),
              'session_error' => false,
               'session_error_message' => array(),
               'url' => ''
           );`  and of course i did remove the redirect and set the url to something useful with this line `$data['url'] = base_url().'admin/dashboard';`

Comment: nice, glad to help ;)